# Graph Theory Question regarding a remark in Hamiltonian Cycles Proof

Tags: graph-theory

I'm going through a set of notes on Graph Theory. The following theorem is proved:

**Theorem 1:** Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ ($ n \geq 3$) such that $ \delta(G) \geq \frac{n}{2} $. Then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

I'm happy with the statement and proof of this theorem. The notes then prove the following theorem:

**Theorem 2:** Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ ($n \geq 3$) such that $G$ is connected and $ \delta(G) \geq \frac{k}{2} $, where $ k < n $. Then $G$ has a path of length k.

I'm happy with the proof of this. The notes then make the following remark

**Remark:** We do need $k < n $, e.g. $ G = K_k $, and we do need $G$ to be connected e.g. two disjoint copies of $K_k$.

I don't understand this remark. Clearly $k$ can't be bigger than $n$ (as there obviously can't be a path through more than $n$ vertices on a graph with $n$ vertices). So the remark must mean we can't have $k = n $. But if $k = n$, then isn't this just the same as Theorem 1? I don't see how the example relates, either; if $ G = K_n $, then the theorem still works?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe the difference is path vs cycle in conjunction with definition of length? If length=number of edges, Hamiltonian cycle can be made into path of length (n-1) by removing an edge, but of course there will be no path of length n.

Comment: A guess: The author is showing why each of the requirements in the statement of Theorem 2 is necessary. I agree that a `Remark' usually refers to something non-obvious.

Comment: I'm still unsure why '$k < n$' is necessary. Why couldn't we have $k \leq n $?

Comment: I guess it comes down to: is a cycle a path?

Comment: You could argue that any graph with at least one edge has paths of unbounded length: just go backwards and forwards on a single edge, as many times as you need. But this lax definition of path is obviously not what is meant in the statement of Theorem 2, so presumably a *simple* path of length $k$ is what is meant. And a cycle is not a simple path, so a simple path can have length at most $n-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different authors define *path* differently, but it appears that the author of your notes uses definitions similar to those used in West’s *Introduction to Graph Theory*. For him a *path* is ‘a simple graph whose vertices can be ordered so that two vertices are adjacent if and only if they are consecutive in the list’, and a *cycle* is ‘a graph with an equal number of vertices and edges whose vertices can be placed around a circle so that two vertices are adjacent if and only if they appear consecutively along the circle’. By these definitions a path can never be a cycle: in any listing of the vertices of a cycle in which consecutive vertices in the list are adjacent to each other in the graph, the first and last vertices in the list are *also* adjacent in the graph. This definition of *path* also implies that no path in a graph can have more vertices than the graph itself. In particular, $K_n$ contains no path with $n+1$ vertices and hence no path of length $n$.

Comment: But the problem arises when $k$ is *equal* to $n$. Then a path can certainly have $n$ distinct vertices! But its length is only $n-1$.

Comment: Yes, the last sentence of the original answer was a bit of a non sequitur, though the correct point was made in the previous sentence. I no longer recall why I wrote it, but I’ve replaced it with one that makes the real point explicitly.